# Weights and biases - saving and loading models to continue training

Tags: wandb

I am trying to set up my model to run, train and save everything into and from Weights and Biases.

I would like to:

1. Load the latest model from W and B and continue training with it from the last epoch that i left on/place it ended on the last model save
2. Save the model

This is my current code to load the model:

artifact = wandb.use_artifact('markstent/sonic-diffusion/sonic-diffusion-model-256:latest', type='model')
artifact_dir = artifact.download()
pipeline = AudioDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(artifact_dir)

This is how im saving it :

model_artifact = wandb.Artifact(
'sonic-diffusion-model-256',
type='model',
description='sonic-diffusion-model-256'
)

```
            model_artifact.add_dir(args.output_dir)
            wandb.log_artifact(
                model_artifact,
                aliases=[f'step_{global_step}', f'epoch_{epoch}']
            )
```

Any tips on optimizing this as its currently not working

The only code i have tried is above....i am currently saving the model as an artifact and then trying to load it when i start my training loop.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Using resume=True in the WandB config solved this.

(NB: it only resumes if the model cuts off in some way prematurely. In this case it will continue from where you ended off training)